# Validate credit or debit card with ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest like validationMode field of Customer Profile

Tags: c#, .net-core, authorize.net

I use ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest using opaqueData to create subsciptions but there is no validationMode like field to validate if the card is active, I would like to know if there is a mechanism similar to the validationMode on Customer Profiles for ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest that allow me to validate the card? Or if by default this endpoint already validates that and if the card is not active then an error code would be returned to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARB does not offer credit card validation as part of creating a subscription. So if you wish to validate a credit card to be used in a subscription you would (and should) use the createTransactionRequest AIM API to do an AUTH_ONLY of $0.00 (or $0.01 if your processing bank does not support zero dollar authorizations) to verify the card is an active credit card.

Keep in mind it does not mean the credit card will still be active when the first subscription payment is attempted nor does it guarantee the funds will be available at that time.

Comment: Thanks John, that sentences were very helpful